# Hoeffding-Type Bounds for Noncentered Variables

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, distribution-tails

[Hoeffding's Tail Bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality) is well-known for subgaussian variables. It can be written in the following way:

Assume $X_i$ for $1\leq i\leq n$ satisfies:
$$
\mathbb{P}(|X_i-\mu|>t)\leq 2\exp\left(\frac{-t^2}{2\sigma_i^2}\right)
$$
Then for $t\geq 0$, we have that:
$$
\mathbb{P}(|\frac{\sum_i X_i}{n}-\mu|>t)\leq 2\exp\left(\frac{-n^2t^2}{2\sum_i \sigma^2}\right)
$$
I am wondering if this can be generalized to the case when the constant is not the mean. i.e. assume that for $X_i$ we have the bounds:
$$
\mathbb{P}(|X_i-a_i|>t)\leq 2\exp\left(\frac{-t^2}{2\sigma_i^2}\right)
$$
Where $\mathbb{E}(X_i)\neq a_i$. Then can we bound:
$$
\mathbb{P}(|\frac{\sum_i X_i-a_i}{n}|>t)
$$
similarly to Hoeffding's bound? I feel like I am missing something obvious but I am quite stuck.